# Is there a way to practice unit testing without having an app built already?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This may seem like a dumb question (I hope not, haha) but I'm gonna be starting my first internship for software engineering this winter & one of the things they want me to do is unit testing.  Is there anyway I can practice this?  In other words, are there already-built dummy apps that allow me to practice unit testing?

The reason why I ask this is because I know they're not gonna want me to build an app from scratch since the app is already made.  Really the only thing left to do is unit test and debug.

I familiar with Android-Studio & Java.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Why the **algorithm** and **oop** tags?

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet You're right, I don't know why I put those there.  I just removed them.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to write unit test then also need to know what particular method of production code (app code)should behave. It seems, you do not have application code at the moment, I think your best bet would be to practice the tool you will be using for unit testing. You can find a lot of resources of unit testing knowing which tool you will be using.

Comment: Hey Faisal, thank you for your response :)  Can you provide me a link that can show me this?

Comment: @stepBack Here is Android Getting Started with Testing link [link](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html)

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The most used unit-testing-framework for Java is [JUnit](http://junit.org). So you may want to read the "Getting started" there.